# How to repaint SWT window?

Tags: java, swt, repaint, invalidation

is there any option to repaint all window in SWT? I have shell with 900 comboboxes and I have to repaint all content of this window in loops (100x) and count how much microseconds it was.

How to create loops and how count time of repainting is not important.

I tried **redraw(), setRedraw(true), layout** and similar advices from few forums but it does not work I think.

I need same functionality like in Swing when I used             **window.invalidate();
            window.validate();
            window.repaint();**

```
public class SwtCombobox {

private static final int numberOFTestingLoops = 100;

protected Shell shell;
private Combo[] comboboxes;

private List<Long> resultOfAnalysisRepaint = new ArrayList<Long>();
private List<Double> resultOfAnalysisMemory = new ArrayList<Double>();

private int counterOfAnalysis = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        SwtCombobox window = new SwtCombobox();
        window.open(window);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void open(SwtCombobox window) {
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    createContents();
    shell.open();
    shell.layout();
    shell.addPaintListener(new MyListener(window));
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {

        if (counterOfAnalysis < numberOFTestingLoops) {
            counterOfAnalysis++;

            shell.redraw();

        } else if (counterOfAnalysis == numberOFTestingLoops) {
            createOutputFile();
            shell.setRedraw(false);

            MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox(shell,
                    SWT.ICON_INFORMATION);
            messageBox.setMessage("Analysis file created.");
            messageBox.open();

            System.exit(0);
        }

        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}

protected void createContents() {

    shell = new Shell();
    shell.setSize(1550, 670);

    comboboxes = new Combo[900];

    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 30; y++) {

            counter++;
            String options[] = { Integer.toString(counter), "test1",
                    "test2" };

            comboboxes[i] = new Combo(shell, SWT.BORDER);
            comboboxes[i].setItems(options);
            comboboxes[i].select(0);
            comboboxes[i].setBounds(y * 51, i * 21, 51, 21);
        }
    }
}

public void repaint() {

    long solStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long solTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - solStart;
    resultOfAnalysisRepaint.add(solTime);
    double currentMemory = ((double) ((double) (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 1024) / 1024)) - ((double) ((double) (Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1024) / 1024)); 
    resultOfAnalysisMemory.add(currentMemory);
}

private void createOutputFile() {
    String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    generateCsvFile(currentDir + "\\outputSwtCombobox.csv",
            resultOfAnalysisRepaint, resultOfAnalysisMemory);
}

private static void generateCsvFile(String sFileName,
        List<Long> resultsRepaint, List<Double> resultsMemory) {
    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName);
        Long averageRepaint = 0L;
        Double averageMemory = 0.0;

        writer.append("RepaintTime");
        writer.append(';');
        writer.append("MemoryUsage");
        writer.append('\n');

        for (int i = 0; i < resultsRepaint.size(); i++) {
            writer.append(resultsRepaint.get(i).toString());
            writer.append(';');

            writer.append(resultsMemory.get(i).toString());
            writer.append('\n');

            averageRepaint = averageRepaint + resultsRepaint.get(i);
            averageMemory = averageMemory + resultsMemory.get(i);
        }

        writer.append('\n');
        writer.append("Average (microseconds):");
        writer.append(';');
        writer.append("Average (MB):");
        writer.append('\n');
        writer.append(String
                .valueOf((averageRepaint / numberOFTestingLoops)));
        writer.append(';');
        writer.append(String
                .valueOf((averageMemory / numberOFTestingLoops)));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

class MyListener implements PaintListener {

```
private SwtCombobox swtCombobox;

public MyListener(SwtCombobox swtCombobox) {
    super();
    this.swtCombobox = swtCombobox;
}

public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
    swtCombobox.repaint();
}
```

}

Comment: redraw() is correct. The actual repaint will be done in a Paint event generated asynchronously.

Comment: I added my code. I used redraw(). This redraw() will be in my code (in loop) called 100x and repainting time for all loops are 0. It is reason why I think that content of  window was not repainted. Please, correct me. Thanks

Comment: You can't just call redraw() repeatedly, you have to let the Display.readAndDispatch() loop run.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand well. May you please type what should I change?